# NetBeans - Replace tabs with spaces on save

Tags: netbeans-8

I need netbeans to replace tabs with spaces on file save.

I already tried: **Tools -> Options -> Editor -> On Save -> Remove Trailing Whitespaces From: All Lines**

and **Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Formatting -> Language: All Languages -> Expand Tabs to Spaces (true)**

But I was unable to find out how to automatically do this on save?

I found out that **Tools -> Options -> Editor -> On Save -> Reformat: All Lines** does kind of what I want, but it also reformats the code...

How does it work?

Comment: Why not just set **Tools -> Options -> Editor -> On Save -> Reformat** to **None**? Then all trailing spaces in the code will be removed without reformatting the code when you save, or am I misunderstanding what you want to achieve?

Comment: It was at none from the start, and tabs where not replaced by spaces. So it does not work this way...

Comment: If I set **Reformat:None** and **Remove Trailing Whitespaces From: All Lines** in the **On Save** tab then it works exactly as expected for me, with one strange exception: if the cursor is positioned within trailing whitespace when saving, then trailing whitespace to the left of the cursor is not removed on that line, though trailing whitespace is removed on all other lines. The cursor issue looks like a bug. I tested using a *.java file on NetBeans 8.2. What version of NetBeans are you using, and what language/file type did you test with?

Comment: @skomisa, hmm strange, maybe the same bug happened for me and I thought it is not working because I did not checked the other lines. Have to test it. I tested it on a xml file I think. I also use NetBeans 8.2. Thanks for your hint!

Comment: I think I just had to restart netbeans, now it seems to work fine.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but **Source > Remove Trailing Spaces** does work exactly as expected, without that cursor issue. But that doesn't help when you are saving the file.